# Div with part transparent background cannot get other divs from flowing into transparent part in codeigniter

Tags: html, css, codeigniter

I am currently using a div with a png background. Part of the png is transparent. I am trying to fit three divs inside the background div but they overflow into the transparent of the png div. My framework is codeigniter.

Here is my HTML

```
<div id="image">
<div id="red">Red</div>
<div id="yellow">Yellow</div>
<div id="green"> Green</div>
```

Here is my css

```
#image{
    background:url(../images/body.png);
    overflow: visible;
    width: 226px;
    height: 321px;
    float: right;
    float: top;
    border:5px solid black;

}
#red
{
    border-style: url(../images/body.png);
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    overflow:hidden; 
    width: 100%;

}
#green
{
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
    overflow:hidden;

}
#yellow
{
    height: 100px;
    background-color: yellow;
    overflow:hidden;

}
```

I do not have enough reputation to post a picture of what I am trying to achieve.
Thank you

Comment: You can add a link to the picture from image hosting site if you need to add an image. Someone with higher rep will attach the image.

Comment: Ram thank you. I ended up placing image then overlaying it with 3 divs.